# Shopify - Show inline element on varient select

Tags: ruby, select, shopify, liquid, variant

Currently I am trying to show/hide an inline element on the page when a specific variant of the product is selected in a `<select>` input. I've tried multiple tries with jquery to access the select with no luck and even tried inline `<% if %>` liquid tag. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Basically I want a `textbox` to show when two of the options are selected else not show the textbox.

Below is what I have:

```
{% if product.variants.size > 1 %}
      <div id="product-variants" class="card_options">
        <select id="product-select-{{ product.id }}" name="id" class="hidden line-item-property__field">
          {% for variant in product.variants %}
          <option {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %} selected="selected" {% endif %} value="{{ variant.id }}" data-sku="{{ variant.sku }}">{{ variant.title }} - {{ variant.price | money }}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>

      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id }}" /> 

{% endif %}
```

Now if only I could add something like below to add the textbox when option1 or option2 are selected.

```
<-- Same as above -->    
{% if product.variants.size > 1 %}
      <div id="product-variants" class="card_options">
        <select id="product-select-{{ product.id }}" name="id" class="hidden line-item-property__field">
          {% for variant in product.variants %}
          <option {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %} selected="selected" {% endif %} value="{{ variant.id }}" data-sku="{{ variant.sku }}">{{ variant.title }} - {{ variant.price | money }}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>

      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id }}" /> 

{% endif %}
<-- End Same as above -->

<-- New Code -->
{% if variant != option1 %}
   <p class="line-item-property__field" id=card_message>
        <label for="card-message">Card Message:</label>
        <span id="char-counter"></span><span id="message-alert"></span>
        <textarea id="message-textarea" maxlength="250" name="properties[Card Message]"></textarea>
   </p>

{% else %}
<span id="placeholder"></span>
{% endif %}
```

This is what it should look like:
[image]

Comment: So bottom line you don't know how to target the select with JS and show the textarea when the last 2 options are selected, right? Yet I don't see any JS code in your question and all of your tags doesn't point that this a JS problem. Can you show us what have you tried based on JS logic, not the liquid one.

Comment: Hello @drip, I actually know quite well how to target the select and its options using JS. The problem is when using a dynamic variant element it seems to be hard to access the select and its options. I have created a Fiddle that I used JS to create the textbox element on the last options selected. But remind you I tried this method and it didn't work on Shopify.
-----[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ryman/drg2vrft/)-----

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Apparently my solution with jQuery worked. I was just targeting the wrong select on the page. I had to retrieve the select dynamically instead of finding it by class or id. For some reason Shopify creates a second `<select>` input and hides the one you see in products.liquid document. So I had to resort to using `$(".selector-wrapper select").bind('change', function(event) {//do something}` and `var selected = $('.selector-wrapper select option:selected').val();` to retrieve the values of the options.  I'll link a fiddle I created with the same logic, you will just have to update it with what I listed above. Hope this helps anyone looking for same solution.

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ryman/drg2vrft/)**